# Can we have the first VTC post a comment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, comments, new-users

I quite often encounter questions with at least one *vote to close* (VTC), but no comment or down vote. This means the OP doesn't know there is anything wrong with the question.

Would it be possible for the first VTC* to post a community comment with the selected vote to close reason. Allowing the OP to be notified there is a VTC?

*I think there would be a benefit to having this happen for first time askers, even if the user has the *[View Close Votes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)* privilege, which is gained at 250 rep.

Comment: I think you've assumed the OP can't see the post is gathering close votes. I recall closing some of my very old SO posts, where I still don't have VTC privileges, and the VTC reason would attribute the close to Community. If this is the case, do you think your desire for a comment on VTC to go?

Comment: This is for OPs that a very early in the CR cycle and don't have enough rep to see close votes yet. We can't force users to leave a comment if they are the first one to VTC, which is what I would prefer. I think the community answer should cite the proper topic in help and perhaps whatever Meta questions apply.

Comment: Ah sorry, you get the _[View Close Votes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)_ privilege at 250 rep. Is your suggestion only for users with <250 rep?

Comment: This has been asked on the main meta before, see for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191213/196432.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I'd say it was primarily for first time questions, that or 250 points for the OP could be a qualifier.